# Live555 Streaming Server RTP Lost Packet Retransmit

Tags: video-streaming, rtsp, rtp, live555, rtcp

Does the live555 streaming server retransmit lost RTP packets?

When I search for "live555 retransmit" it turns up a few results:

- In 2011 [Francesco Tonelli described a mechanism to implement retransmission of lost packets](http://lists.live555.com/pipermail/live-devel/2011-January/013084.html). This means there was no such mechanism at that time.
- In 2013 [Zvika Meiseles tried to implement a queue to determine when to retransmit a lost packet](http://lists.live555.com/pipermail/live-devel/2013-January/016502.html). The discussion was about using the frame duration reported by the framer: The "MPEG2TransportStreamFramer" class should be scanning the "PTS" (timestamps) in the incoming MPEG Transport Stream packets, and using this to compute an estimated 'duration' for each. Again this means the retransmission was not built into live555.
- In 2016 [Mathijs Vos asked whether it should send a RR once the client detects a lost packet](http://lists.live555.com/pipermail/live-devel/2016-February/019910.html). The answer was that the RTCP-based retransmission mechanism, - i.e. the RTP/AVPF in RFC 4585 and RFC 4588, was not implemented at that time.

Does anybody know whether it is implemented by live555 itself now? Or any other implementations out there?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is better suited for the Live555 mailing list.

Comment: The very reason this question is asked here, not on the live555 mailing list, is because after reading discussions on the live555 mailing list and related questions here on SO, I believed in a better chance of getting an answer here, not on the mailing list.

Comment: Or if I figure it out, I'd like to post an answer here to share with more people instead of the mailing list.